# How to use a self join to get the COUNT of how many people on my platform have worked at another company prior to my current one using MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, self-join

I have a table in the form:

| id | comp | employment_year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ShoesCo | 2000 |
| 1 | FeetOrg | 2006 |
| 1 | SizeEight | 2012 |
| 2 | ShoesCo | 2001 |
| 2 | SizeEight | 2004 |
| 2 | FeetOrg | 2007 |
| 3 | SizeEight | 2001 |
| 3 | ShoesCo | 2004 |
| 3 | FeetOrg | 2007 |

I want to count (get the total) number of people who worked at **ShoesCo** *prior* to (`employment_date`) working at **SizeEight**. The `id` is the uniqueid for each employee. I am thinking of self-join but have limited experience with SQL.

The answer should be 2 for this example.

Comment: Did you decide self join is the way to go or were you told to do it that way?

Comment: I was told do it that way; but other suggestions are valued @P.Salmon

Comment: Considering that your title says "MySQL" I have removed [[tag:tsql]], as that is the dialect for SQL Server (and SyBase).

Comment: *people who worked at ShoesCo prior to (employment_date) working at SizeEight* If an employee works in ShoesCo then in SizeEight then again in ShoesCo? If backward?

Comment: @Akina Let's assume that they can only work at each company once. If that answers your query

Comment: No assuming. Either forbid by according constraint or possible (for example as a result of application fail). Anycase - what is **precise** MySQL version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the data have no duplicates by `(id,comp)` then

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id)
FROM table t1
JOIN table t2 USING (id)
WHERE t1.comp = 'ShoesCo'
  AND t2.comp = 'SizeEight'
  AND t1.employment_year < t2.employment_year
```

Comment: thanks, if there were duplicates?

Comment: @Mazil_tov998 Expand counting expression. Something like `COUNT(DISTINCT id, t1.employment_year)`.